# Eval() not executing even though syntax is correct

Tags: javascript, syntax, eval

I'm trying to execute an event listener using eval()

```
["document.addEventListener('load', "].forEach(f => {
  eval(f + `function(){ console.log("test") })`)
})
```

The console never logs however.
When I replace eval() with console.log, it shows that the string has correct syntax

```
["document.addEventListener('load', "].forEach(f => {
  console.log(f + 'function(){ console.log("test") })');
}) // logs 'document.addEventListener('load', function(){ console.log("test") })'
```

So if the syntax is correct, what's the problem?

When I remove '`function()`' from the string and just directly fire '`console.log`', it works.

```
["document.addEventListener('load', "].forEach(f => {
  eval(f + 'console.log("nice"))');
}) // this works
```

Comment: The event listener only fires on a load event which likely already happened

Comment: @Scrapper142 but when I remove 'function()' from the string and just directly fire 'console.log', like eval(f + 'console.log("nice"))', it works. If it were the window loading already happening, wouldn't it not work either way?

Comment: In the second example the string its evaluating ends up being `'document.addEventListener('load', console.log("nice"))'`, so since you are directly executing `console.log("nice")`, it executes it (thats when it prints), but then adds the event handler becomes undefined

Comment: Ah you're right. Is there an alternative to document.addEventListener('load") that I can use? I need to perform this function right at the start of the app.

Comment: Does it need to access elements on the page?

Comment: Yes, the actual eval() content will be setting innerHTML values. I need to set innerHTML values right when the app starts, and then later when a slider is inputted (that's why I'm doing a forEach, the second string will be an eventListener for inputting an element.)

Answer (score 1):

Moved here because longer answer

You could try a function that takes the code string, and runs it immediately if the page is loaded otherwise add an event listener

```js
function runWhenLoaded(codeString) {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') { // checks if it is loaded already
    eval(codeString);
  else {
    document.addEventListener('load', () => eval(codeString));
  }
}
```

Comment: Then you can add another event listener for the slider